# How to solve socket error while accessing data from wikipedia using python

Tags: python, pandas, sockets, csv, pickle

I am trying to access the data set from Wikipedia using python ,  the purpose of the code is to access a  table of S&p500 companies and extract the data set into a csv file (each company data in one csv file ) some of the data are well accessed but i am getting socket exception which i am find little hard to understand.I am giving my complete code

```
import bs4 as bs
import datetime as dt
import os
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pickle
import requests


def save_sp500_tickers():
resp = requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text,  'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})
tickers = []
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    ticker = row.findAll('td')[0].text
    tickers.append(ticker)

with open("sp500tickers.pickle","wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(tickers,f)

return tickers

#save_sp500_tickers()


def get_data_from_yahoo(reload_sp500=False):

if reload_sp500:
    tickers = save_sp500_tickers()
else:
    with open("sp500tickers.pickle","rb") as f:
        tickers = pickle.load(f)

if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs'):
    os.makedirs('stock_dfs')

start = dt.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime(2016, 12, 31)

for ticker in tickers:
    # just in case your connection breaks, we'd like to save our progress!
    if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
        df = web.DataReader(ticker, "yahoo", start, end)
        df.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
    else:
        print('Already have {}'.format(ticker))

 get_data_from_yahoo()
```

I got the exception as follows

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Jeet Chatterjee\Data Analysis With Python for finance\op6.py", line 49, in <module>
get_data_from_yahoo()
     File "C:\Users\Jeet Chatterjee\Data Analysis With Python for finance\op6.py", line 44, in get_data_from_yahoo
df = web.DataReader(ticker, "yahoo", start, end)
     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 121, in DataReader
session=session).read()
       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\yahoo\daily.py", line 115, in read
df = super(YahooDailyReader, self).read()
       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 181, in read
params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 79, in _read_one_data
out = self._read_url_as_StringIO(url, params=params)
       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 90, in _read_url_as_StringIO
response = self._get_response(url, params=params)
        File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 139, in _get_response
raise RemoteDataError('Unable to read URL: {0}'.format(url))
     pandas_datareader._utils.RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AGN?period1=946665000&period2=1483208999&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=6JtBOAj%5Cu002F6EP
```

Please help me in solving this , thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not too much wrong with what you're doing, one problem is that Yahoo timeseries data isn't guaranteed to be available 100% of the time, it does tend to appear and disappear. I just looked on the Yahoo site; while there doesn't seem to be a problem with Allergan (AGN), which is the one that failed for you, at the time I tried Brown Forman (BF.B) and Berkshire Hathaway B (BRK.B) were unavailable.

Another problem is that you can't assume that every symbol on the S&P 500 will have timeseries data in the ranges you have hard-coded; some only exist for 2017.

The following is a slightly modified version of your code that makes the best effort to fetch all the symbols, requesting data from 1 Jan 2000 to the current day, and just giving up if Yahoo doesn't have the data available.

At the time of writing this was able to fetch timeseries for 503 of the 505 symbols currently on the S&P 500. Note I used a proxy server, you can just delete or comment out this part of the code.

```
import bs4 as bs
import datetime as dt
import os
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pickle
import requests

# proxy servers for internet connection
proxies = {
    'http': 'http://my.proxy.server:8080',
    'https': 'https://my.proxy.server:8080',
}

symbol_filename = "sp500tickers.pickle"

def save_sp500_tickers():    
    resp = requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies', proxies=proxies)
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text,  'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})
    tickers = []
    for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
        ticker = row.findAll('td')[0].text
        tickers.append(ticker)
    with open(symbol_filename,"wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(tickers,f)
    return tickers


def get_data_from_yahoo(reload_sp500=False):
    if reload_sp500 or not os.path.exists(symbol_filename):
        tickers = save_sp500_tickers()
    else:
        with open(symbol_filename,"rb") as f:
            tickers = pickle.load(f)

    if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs'):
        os.makedirs('stock_dfs')

    start = dt.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
    end = dt.datetime(dt.date.today().year, dt.date.today().month, dt.date.today().day) 

    for ticker in tickers:
        if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
            try:
                print ticker
                df = web.DataReader(ticker, "yahoo", start, end)
                df.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
            except:
                print ("No timeseries available for " + ticker)
        else:
            pass # print('Already have {}'.format(ticker))


os.environ["HTTP_PROXY"]=proxies['http']
os.environ["HTTPS_PROXY"]=proxies['https']
get_data_from_yahoo()
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: thank u very much , it worked .Can you explain why u have defined the proxy ?

Comment: @Mandrek I only defined the proxy as I was running this on a company network and they require all HTTP requests to go through an HTTP proxy server. If I don't define the proxy I can't make the calls, that's all.